# How do you re-initialize node-pty to a different shell type?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, xtermjs, node-pty

I'm setting up an in-browser terminal using xterm.js, react, and node-pty. I've got the node-pty process running on a server via websockets. The terminal actually works and it's visible in the react UI. I'm able to initialize the terminal to `node` or `python3` on first load using this:

```
        client.tty = pty.spawn("node", [], {
            name: "xterm-color",
            cols: 80,
            rows: 24,
            cwd: process.env.PWD,
            env: process.env
        });
```

I'm able to kill this process like this:

```
    self.on("message", function(client, msg) {
        if (msg === "kill") {
          client.tty.kill(9);        
        }
        client.tty && client.tty.write(msg);
    });
```

This listener fires anytime a character is typed into the terminal in the UI.

This doesn't feel like the idiomatic way to handle this, but what I'm looking to do, is emit a message from a websocket in the UI, which depends on react state, and respawn a new `node-pty` terminal with a different initial shell ie switch from `node` to `python3`.

I figured out that destroying the HTML node where the terminal exists causes the `open` listener on the server to fire again, but I don't think it's possible to include a message when it reopens.

```
    self.on("open", (client, test) => {
        client.tty = pty.spawn("node", [], {
            name: "xterm-color",
            cols: 80,
            rows: 24,
            cwd: process.env.PWD,
            env: process.env
        });

        const ttyId = client.tty._pty
        client.tty.on("exit", function(code, signal) {
            client.tty = null;
            client.close();
        });

        client.tty.on("data", (data) => {
            client.send(data);
        });
    });
```

My question is, how do you respawn the `node-pty` process and dynamically change the shell type?

Comment: You cannot directly respawn a PTY. Several options: discard old one, spawn a new one (preferred option). Second option - if the current process allows access to `exec*` calls, you could try to replace the executed process (only do this if you know what you are doing). Third option - create a 2nd slave endpoint, spawn 2nd process there and close the 1st endpoint. `node-pty` does not expose enough primitives to do that reliably, thus again at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks Jerch! How would you discard the old and spawn a new one?

Comment: On POSIX systems either SIGHUP (closing the PTY) or killing the session leader (your first process) should do the trick. On Windows it is not that easy due to missing strong parent-child process relation, and no signals at all. There you gonna need a process watcher to cleanup things manually.

Comment: And spawning a new one is easy - just create another PTY with the other command and route your data accordingly.

Comment: One more remark - if your main processes are `node` and `python` in interactive mode then you have to implement a PTY turnover anyway to properly deal with Ctrl+C or Ctrl+D keystrokes, both behave similar to SIGHUP and killing, leaving the terminal unusable without any PTY re-bootrapping in the background.

Comment: Hi Jerch, would you be able to provide an example of the code to achieve this?

Comment: Yes I would for the pty turnover, but not as working code. For that too many circumstances are unclear: Should it run the PTYs next to each other, one just being "detached" from the terminal (which would need some interim logging mechs)? Or always kill the other one? How to go about the terminal state in between, reset it? What about child processes spawned and not caught by SIGHUP? PTY interaction is somewhat tricky, as it needs some understanding of process control of the underlying OS.If you really just want to connect another PTY to the same terminal, well just do that?